# Intermittent Maps API errors

Tags: google-maps-api-3

We've been using Google Maps API v3 on our website for a few months, with everything working fine.  Then, suddenly, today we've started seeing intermittent errors saying:

"Google has disabled use of the Maps API for this application.  The provided key is not a valid Google API Key, or it is not authorized for the Google Maps Javascript API v3 on this site."

I went back and checked the API console, and everything appears fine, and how I left it when we first set it up.  Given the intermittent nature, I'm suspecting some transient problem with Google's servers.

Has anyone seen this sort of behavior before, or happen to know what might be causing it?

Comment: Do you have a link to your site?

Comment: Sorry for the delay... I figured out the problem.  The referrer url pattern I had was missing a trailing asterisk.  Odd thing is that it was working for ~3 months since I first set it up.  Perhaps Google fixed a bug there.

Comment: Is that a definitive answer? I have trailing asterisks and am still seeing the problem. Also, do you know whether the protocol https should be specified in the referrer url pattern?